# Python - OpenCV - Binarize To Isolate Object Which is Same Color as Background

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, signal-processing

I need to isolate the cardboard target in the image below and binarize it, so that the target is white and the background black. Normally, this is not a problem, but the background is almost the exact same color as the target.

Attempts:

```
# LOAD IMAGE
img_filepath = 'real_6.png'
img = cv2.imread( img_filepath )
rgb_img = img[:,:,::-1]
plt.imshow( rgb_img )
plt.title('ORIGINAL')
plt.show()

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor( img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY )

# SMOOTH
blur_kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.float32)/30
blur_img = cv2.filter2D( rgb_img, -1, blur_kernel )

# THRESHOLD 
lower_color_rng = np.array( [100,50,100] )
upper_color_rng = np.array( [255,255,255] )
target_keyholes_img = cv2.inRange( blur_img, lower_color_rng, upper_color_rng )
plt.imshow( target_keyholes_img, cmap='gray' )
plt.title( 'THRESHOLD' )
plt.show()
```

[Attempted Image Extraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joml8.png)

How can I use OpenCV in Python 3 to binarize this image?

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Mecw.png)

Comment: you can try grabcut opencv algorithm for foreground extraction

Comment: If the color of your object is slightly different (as in the example image you provided), you can try to find the correct threshold that divides it from the background. If the color is in fact **the same** as your background, there is no way to isolate it.